# Linked SQL Server Issue

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have 3 servers all running Windows Server 2016 Datacenter:

Server1 is a domain controller and has ssms installed for accessing SQL Server Instances on Server2 and Server3

Server2 & Server3 are running SQL Server Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU3)

Server2 has a linked server link to Server3

Server3 has a linked server link to Server2

If I log onto server2 and run a select query which uses the link to server3

```
Select top 5 * from [Server3].[DB3].[dbo].[TableName]
```

It runs fine and results are returned.

If I log onto server3 and run a select query which uses the link to server2

```
Select top 5 * from [Server2].[DB2].[dbo].[TableName]
```

It runs fine and results are returned.

But If I log onto Server1 and open ssms, connect to Server2 and run query

```
Select top 5 * from [Server3].[DB3].[dbo].[TableName]
```

I receive error 'Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.'

And the same happens if I log onto Server1, open ssms, connect to server3 and run query

```
Select top 5 * from [Server2].[DB2].[dbo].[TableName]
```

I am logging onto all 3 servers using the same domain credentials, but it feels to me like if im running the query from Server1, then its not passing my credentials through causing the query to be ran against the target sql instance as NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON

Comment: I've voted to move this question to [Stack DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com), as I think you are more likely to get an answer there.  If you agree you can move by clicking: Close >> off-topic because... >> This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network >> belongs on dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Have a look at Security tab in Linked Server Properties of Server2 on Server1.

Comment: @Denis Rubashkin - The security is set to 'Be made using the login's current security context'. destination-data - I agree and will move it, thanks for that suggestion.